# 401 (Unauthorized) request on Angular 7, .netcore application

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

Iam getting a 401 unauthorized error while authorizing an user to consume an api on .net core and angular 7 application.

My angular service has a function :-

```
getUserProfile() {
   var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')});
   console.log(tokenHeader)
   return this.http.get('/api/ApplicationUser/UserProfile', { headers: tokenHeader});
}
```

on tokenHeader I am sending the user jwt token.

My api is

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("UserProfile")]
//'api/userProfile'
public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
{
    string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    return new { user.fullName, user.Email, user.UserName };
}
```

I have tried some answers from other questions but nothing helps.

Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  })
};

return this.http.get('/api/ApplicationUser/UserProfile', httpOptions);
```

Also make sure you have this line in your controller

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Comment: @AmeerPappay check my answer again

Comment: if possible can u just tell me what idea changed here?
i have followed a tutorial and they didn't added any params to Authorize , but worked fine

Comment: I think the error come from your Angular code. My code is common way to setup the header in angular

Comment: how can i specify responseType in this? where to specify
{responseType: 'text'}

Comment: Add after the authorization

Comment: tried it
but still gettting error "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8842/api/Data/SaveHoliday"

Comment: `
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        responseType:'text'
      })
    };
`

Comment: ``const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text'
    }``

this is working now

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your request from network tab. 
Also I recommend to use interceptors for make it global

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 private isRefreshing = false;
 private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

 constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   if (this.authService.getJwtToken()) {
     request = this.addToken(request, this.authService.getJwtToken());
   }

   return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
     if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
       return this.handle401Error(request, next);
     } else {
       return throwError(error);
     }
   }));
 }

 private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
   return request.clone({
     setHeaders: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     }
   });
 }

 private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
   if (!this.isRefreshing) {
     this.isRefreshing = true;
     this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

     return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
       switchMap((token: any) => {
         this.isRefreshing = false;
         this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.jwt);
         return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.jwt));
       }));

   } else {
     return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
       filter(token => token != null),
       take(1),
       switchMap(jwt => {
         return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
       }));
   }
 }
}
```

Full example https://github.com/bartosz-io/jwt-auth-angular/blob/master/src/app/auth/token.interceptor.ts